# How to load Identity Login page to a Home page using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-identity, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm attempting to create the ability to load on the right hand of my page the `Login.chtml` page from the identity area on a home page using ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. I followed all the instructions to create the ID framework in my existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application and the login link works like a charm but for the life of me I can't seem to load the page.

I tried calling it directly a few different ways but I always get some kind of InvalidOperation exception

FYI this is an existing ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application that used migrations to add MS Identity

Comment: You should post the code you've used in an attempt to get Login.cshtml to render. Are you trying to render the Login page as a partial view?

Comment: currently i have this in my _loginPartial.chtml...
 See Next comment
now i want to replace the   <a class="nav-link text-dark" id="login" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>

to actually load the \Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml in that area instead 


i tried in my Program.cs file to add app.MapAreaControllerRoute for searching a partial but it still dosent find it

Comment: it wont let me add more code... let me add it a few at a time

Comment: i tried to add app.MapAreaControllerRoute
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapRazorPages();

Comment: @Html.RenderPartial("Login") doesn't work?

Comment: no and either does  <partial name="Login" />

Comment: i get 
InvalidOperationException: The partial view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/Login.es.cshtml
/Views/Home/Login.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.es.cshtml
/Views/Shared/Login.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Login.es.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/Login.cshtml

Comment: im sure is some routing issue i just cam seem to figure out what to add to have it look at Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Login.cshtml

Comment: Try @Html.RenderPartial("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml")

Comment: No Joy  - Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'object'

Comment: Try @Html.Partial("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml"), you verified that in your project: /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Login.cshtml is the proper path for this partial view?

Comment: so that getts me to the page but then it blows up on
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>

object not set to a Reference error

Comment: Hey @Waragi i got it ... i just decided to make the Identity Login Page the default page 
i added 
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
              name: "login",
              areaName: "Identity",
              pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Account}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
to my Program.cs and restyled the Login page to look like the home page ... i was hoping for something more elegant but Meh :-) ... thanks for the assist up to this point .. they need to make a blended MVC and Razor app a little more compatible when using Ident and MVC Core6

Comment: Identity is a mess in ASP.net Core. I just use Auth0 for everything.